# Discrepancy when calculating geometrical size of string

Tags: swift, appkit, textkit

Why are the results of `NSAttributedString.size()` and `NSLayoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange:in:).size` so different?

Example code:

```swift
let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]

let container = NSTextContainer()
container.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
container.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
container.containerSize = NSSize(width: 5e6, height: 5e6)
let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
layoutManager.addTextContainer(container)
let text = NSTextStorage()
text.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

text.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "Hello, world!", attributes: attrs))
var range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
print(text.size())
print(layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: range, in: container).size)

text.setAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "東京", attributes: attrs))
range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
print(text.size())
print(layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: range, in: container).size)
```

Here's the result I get:

```
(80.3837890625, 18.0)
(80.3837890625, 17.0)
(25.85410895660203, 14.0)
(25.85410895660203, 19.463557481765747)
```

As you can see, although the widths are the same, the heights are not. In the first case the `NSLayoutManager` reports a smaller height than `NSAttributedString`, and in the second case a larger one.

What accounts for this difference?

I have read the documentation for these two methods. I have also read the Text System Storage Layer Overview in Apple's archive. I could not find the information there.

Comment: Duplicate of [NSAttributedString boundingRect returns wrong height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54497598/nsattributedstring-boundingrect-returns-wrong-height/54501223#54501223)